# Gensim Word2Vec lacks vectors for input words

Tags: gensim, word2vec

Gensim Word2Vec that I've trained lacks vectors for some words. That is, although I have a word "yuval" as an input, the model lacks a vector for it. What is the cause?

Answer (score 1):

You either didn't supply `'yuval'` as a token with a properly-formatted corpus, or the number of occurrences was below the model's `min_count`. (It's generally *helpful* for a `Word2Vec` model to discard low-frequency words – more data isn't automatically better if there are only a few examples of a word.)

Double-check that `'yuval'` appears in the corpus, and how many times, and whether that's sufficient for the word to survive `min_count` trimming.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on `@gojomo`'s answer, `Word2Vec` models during training are told to discard tokens below a `min_count`, as they are considered to be uninformative, meaning unable to extrapolate useful context.

*This means, those tokens wont have vectors.*

To check this, you an load the model, and check that the vocabulary contains the token you are interested in:

```
>>> import gensim
>>> model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load(...)
>>> 'car' in model
True
>>> 'yuval' in model
False
```

Since 'yuval' is not in the vocabulary, it can't be found with the `in` operator, and will throw a key error if used.

```
>>> model['car']
...
...
<numpy array>
>>> model['yuval']
...
...
KeyError: "word 'yuval' not in vocabulary"
```

If you really expect that the word should be in the list of vocabulary words, you can always print them out too:

```
>>> for token in model.wv.vocab.keys():
...     print(token)
...
```